# jquery $.each loop twice - scraping a data inside form

Tags: jquery, web-scraping

This is the html I have:

```
<form name="myDiv">
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="myClass">First field1</td>
        <td class="myClass">Second field1</td>
        <td class="myClass">Third field1</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</form>
<form name="myDiv">
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="myClass">First field2</td>
        <td class="myClass">Second field2</td>
        <td class="myClass">Third field2</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</form>
<form name="myDiv">
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="myClass">First field3</td>
        <td class="myClass">Second field3</td>
        <td class="myClass">Third field3</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</form>
```

I'm trying to scrape this but don't know how to do it.

I was thinking of jQuery and console output and then figure out how to get to outside file once I got the data.

I need data to look like this (or something similar that I can import to db at later stage):

```
First field1,Second field1,Third field1
First field2,Second field2,Third field2
First field3,Second field3,Third field3
```

What I tried was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each( $('form[name=myDiv]'), function() {
        console.log('myDiv:');
        $.each( $(this).find('.myClass'), function(){
            console.log('td data:')
            console.log($('td').html())
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I can get it to log `myDiv` three times but don't know how to iterate through `td` descendants.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You have table elements, such as the <tr> and <td> tags inside of a div, and not a table as they should be. You also have nested <tr> tags, which I do not believe is valid HTML. Do you have the ability to modify this markup?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware. I trimmed it down a bit. Real version is even worse.

Comment: It appears to be a `form` element issue. I will update my code to make it more like real code I have. Sorry about the oversimplification.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).text()` to get each of the `td` elements text:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[name=myDiv]').each(function() {
        console.log('myDiv:');
        $(this).find('.myClass').each(function() {
            console.log('td data:');
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to log `td data:`, in other words it doesn't run the second `.each()`.

Comment: @dbr okay, could you try with an updated version of the code? Thanks.

Comment: Still nothing, it doesn't log `td data:`

Comment: Update: OK, this looks exactly the same as @Josh's answer which works fine in jsfiddle so I guess in my simplification I fixed what is bugging me in the real example. I'm done for tonight. Be back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I've written some code that should work, but also updated your HTML to be more semantic. https://jsfiddle.net/Shuaso/234xtacy/1/

HTML:

```
<table name="myDiv">
  <tr>
    <td class="myClass">A</td>
    <td class="myClass">B</td>
    <td class="myClass">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="myClass">One</td>
    <td class="myClass">Two</td>
    <td class="myClass">Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="myClass">Do</td>
    <td class="myClass">Re</td>
    <td class="myClass">Mi</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="output">

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $("tr").each(function() {
  $("#output").append("<p>")
    $(this).find("td").each(function() {
      var content = $(this).text();
      $("#output").append(content + ", ")
    });
    $("#output").append("</p>")
  });
```

What I've done here is run an each function on every table row of the table, then, run a nested each function to save the content of the `<td>` to a variable named "content", then printed that "content" variable to a div ("#output") below the table. I've also printed out an opening `<p>` tag before I run the each function on each `<td>` as well as a closing `</p>` tag afterwards for proper formatting, as you requested.

Comment: It's not my html, I'm just scraping the data, original is even worse. This seems to work in jsfiddle so it should work for me but I can't figure out why it isn't. It could be me missing something simple or maybe the author knew what s\he was doing and this combination of bad html makes it harder to scrape. Be back tomorrow, thanks for the fiddle.